# Помогите разобраться. О чём идёт речь?

Tags: грамматика

*Невыполнение требования Правил дорожного движения об остановке перед стоп-линией, обозначенной дорожными знаками или разметкой проезжей части дороги, при запрещающем сигнале светофора или запрещающем жесте регулировщика.*  
 
Знак (белая табличка) называется стоп линия. Разметка (белая полоса) тоже называется стоп линия. Вопрос, о чем идёт речь, о знаке или полосе?

Answer (score 1):

Речь идёт о нарушении требования, прописанного в ПДД.   *Не остановились перед стоп-линией*.

Факт нарушения обозначен, а далее идёт разъяснение, что называется *стоп-линией*, и указываются её виды — разметка-полоса и знак-табличка. То есть неважно, перед каким из двух видов стоп-линии кто-то не остановился. Нарушение уже есть.